# Ноутбук Asus X301A под Linux Debian - не работает звук, кардридер и нет драйвера на видеокарту

Tags: ноутбук, debian, linux

Владельцы Asus X301A (X301A-RX150D) Intel Core i3 - 3110M, 2,4GHz, 4Gb, 500Gb, Intel HD Graphics 4000, звук Built-in Speakers And Microphone Altec Lansing® Speakers

Как Вы решили эти вопросы?

1.SD карточка в card reader (SD/MMC) не читается 2.Быстрые клавиши Asus fn+ не работают3.Звука нет4.Драйвер видеокарты я не нашёл...

Comment: а что там в     # lspci

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поставить Ubuntu 12.10. В принципе то же дебиан, только подразукрашенный. Работает довольно хорошо. Сам пользуюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Как это не работает?У меня стоит debian wheezy + xfce4 -> видеокарта вместе с ядром поставилась (как lan и wifi) потому правда добавил firmware-atheros и firmware-realtek + alsa alsa-base alsa-utils (для звука) после установки нужно выставить звукfn завелись только f1 f2 f10 f7 f11 f12 f8Яркость и выключение тачпада уже достравивал...А поставить убунту действительно легче, но... Слишком много хлама ставится из коробки!Карточка в кардридере читается (правда не все) но это не проблема дебиана - в windows вообще, когда кардридер вытягиваешь, комп ни с того ни с сего перезагружется(Просто если вы уж ставите linux, то потрудитесь разобраться как он работает, это вам не windows, где все мышкой решается, будьте готовы к тому, что нужно лезть в логи, конфиги, прописывать настройки - если вы же к этому не готовы, то зачем слезать с windows?Для настройки горячих клавиш (fun) нужно установить acpi acpi-support acpi-utils и добавить модуль asus-acpi и asus-laptop тогда все прекрасно работает!